# Setting up Jest and Enzyme to test React 15 cannot find module react/lib/ReactTestUtils

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react project and am trying to setup some tests

Due to the following setup guides / issues:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1353 ,
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7386 ,
- http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content ,
- http://airbnb.io/enzyme/

I have installed the following dependencies:

- react-addons-test-utils 15.3.2
- react 15.4.0-rc.4
- react-dom 15.4.0-rc-4
- jest 16.0.2
- babel-jest 16.0.0
- babel-preset-es2015 6.18.0
- babel-preset-es2015-loose 7.0.0
- babel-preset-react 6.16.0

My package.json contains the following Jest configuration:

```
 "jest": {
    "bail": false,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.js",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 50,
        "lines": 50,
        "statements": 50
      }
    },
    "globals": {
      "SOURCEMAP": true
    },
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src",
      "<rootDir>/sass",
      "<rootDir>/public",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "resetModules": true,
    "testPathDirs": [
      "<rootDir>/test"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/test/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
    "verbose": true
  }
```

I have my component (GenericButton) placed in `<rootDir>/components/buttons/GenericButton.js` and my test in `<rootDir>/test/componnets/buttons/GenericButtonTest.js` with contents as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import GenericButton from 'components/buttons/GenericButton';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'

describe('Generic Button', () => {
    test('Button action called when clicked', () => {
        var clicked = false;
        const component = shallow(
            <GenericButton action={() => {
                clicked = true;
            }}/>
        );

        console.log("Clicking the button!");
        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(component);
        expect(clicked).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

My babelrc file is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015-loose",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-root-slash-import",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "compact": true,
  "ignore": [
    "/node_modules/(?!react-number-input)"
  ]
}
```

when I run my test however, I get the following error:

```
> admin-console@4.1.0 test C:\path\to\project
> jest

 FAIL  test\components\buttons\GenericButtonTest.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactTestUtils' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:144:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-addons-test-utils\index.js:1:107)
      at node_modules\enzyme\build\react-compat.js:128:19

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.843s
Ran all test suites.
  console.error node_modules\enzyme\build\react-compat.js:131
    react-addons-test-utils is an implicit dependency in order to support react@0.13-14. Please add the appropriate version to your devDependencies. See https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#installation

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What can I do to make this simple test pass?

---

Edit: The file react/lib/ReactTestUtils which react-addons-test-utils is requiring is not in the node_modules/react/lib folder.

This was fixed by upgrading react-addons-test-utils to 15.4.0-rc.3 but then I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$t476n6b4jes0zxw0n18vbzkt9' of undefined

  at getClosestInstanceFromNode (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOMComponentTree.js:106:11)
  at Object.getInstanceFromNode (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOMComponentTree.js:140:14)
  at Object.click (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:326:74)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test\components\buttons\GenericButtonTest.js:17:67)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `ReactTestUtils` and  `enzyme` together in your test at the moment. Fortunately you can simulate the click with enzyme as well. The only problem is that `simulate` does not propagate to the components childs, so you need to find the child first and call `simulate` on it.

```
import React from 'react';
import GenericButton from 'components/buttons/GenericButton';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

describe('Generic Button', () => {
    test('Button action called when clicked', () => {
        var clicked = false;
        const component = shallow(
            <GenericButton action={() => {
                clicked = true;
            }}/>
        );
        component.find('selectrorOfChildWithClickHandler').first().simulate('click')
        expect(clicked).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

Comment: ReferenceError: click is not defined
  --------  at Object.<anonymous> (test\components\buttons\GenericButtonTest.js:18:42)
  --------  at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: There is a typo in my answer.

Comment: that error solved. now:
 Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
----- at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:1401:17)
-----at ShallowWrapper.props (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:791:21)
-----at ShallowWrapper.prop (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:997:21)
-----at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:762:28)
-----at Object.<anonymous> (test\components\buttons\GenericButtonTest.js:17:33)
-----at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: Sorry, updated it again, needs `first()` to get the first node from the result list

Comment: thank you. not it seems that what is left is only an issue with my actual component as the variable didn't get updated. (unless you see something blatantly obvious i'll look into it a bit more myself now)

Answer (score 2):

Enzyme needs these dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev enzyme
npm i --save-dev react-addons-test-utils
npm i --save-dev react-dom
```

to be installed as `devDependencies`. This worked for me.